# Can I use SQL UPDATE Statement in Salesforce Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

I am trying to update a boolean field of my Data Extension based on the value of some other field. can I use SQL `UPDATE` statement to do so? Though when I tried writing this query, it gave me an error

> "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UPDATE'."

If `UPDATE` cannot work, is there any other approach by which we can do this?

Something like:

```
UPDATE [Table1] a
SET a.Field1 = 'True'
WHERE a.Field2 IN ('1','2','3','4')
```

Answer (score 4):

No, only SELECT statements are allowed.

You can, however, specify `Update`, `Overwrite` or `Append` as the action on the target Data Extension.

**Reference**

- [**Marketing Cloud SQL Reference**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/sql_reference/)

Answer (score -2):

No you cannot use UPDATE statements in MC query activities. Please find below link for reference,
https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/query_activity_reference/

Also can you tell the purpose why you need to update data in DE when its already been sync with SFDC data!?

Comment: Thanks, Adam and Gops! I actually got this query resolved using **CASE** statement. I wanted to update the boolean fields in a DE with True or False values to use it directly in email template using Ampscript. eg, If a person purchased the product 1{which is a boolean field(Field1) in DE}, I could directly use %%[ IF Field1 == "true" THEN ]%% {content region for product1}